# Posting content and upload file on Wordpress with Load Balancer

Tags: wordpress

My question is, if we create some post and upload some file (like image file) during the load balancer read server 1 how can it copied image to server 2?

The content will stored on database server (example server 3), so how about the image i uploaded into server 1, when load balancer read server 2 the image will not display right because it was stored on server 1?

Comment: We achieved this using a CDN on server 1, so when server 2 calls the page it loads the image from the CDN instead of the server. WordPress is quite hard to load balance but is possible if you have time and resources to set it up. Other than that you can use pre built solutions, but will have to pay for it.

Comment: @JohanPretorius how do you manage plugins? Are they installed from the web UI or installed as part of deployment process?

Comment: We went with the deployment process, but also optimized the site to not use plugins that arent absolutely needed (Went from 30+ to only about 6),.its still a work in progress.

Comment: So any attachment better upload to somewhere like Amazon S3?

Comment: @X3Inspire Yes, there are plugins that help you sync or move the uploads to external storage